# Display a Date that is stored in SQL Server as Char yyyy-mm-dd as mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: sql-server

I have a `char` column that stores dates as `yyyy-mm-dd`. I need to display these dates as `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If at all possible you should always use the right data type for the job.  Storing dates in strings allows out of range errors (2016-12-32 is a valid string).  It also makes it harder to carry out simple operations like this.  Read up on the [substring function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx), if you are confident all your data follows the exacte yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of your problem is because you are using the wrong datatype. Dates should stored as dates. Anything else is nothing but a pain to work with. To get your formatting you will first have to convert your string to a date so 
you can format it.

Here is an example.

```
select convert(date, YourDateColumn, 101)
```

You can read more about convert here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a link only answer. I suggested they would need to use CONVERT to get around a poor design decision. I will include an example. :)

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+ you could try

```
Select Format(GetDate(),'MM-dd-yyyy')
```

Returns

08-03-2016

To convert the string

```
Select Format(cast('2016-08-03' as date),'MM-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: This produces the desired results but the Format function is pretty slow. So this will not likely perform well on a large dataset. No approach is going to be super fast but FORMAT is so slow. http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the link and the tip.  I tend not to use the format, IMHO, formatting should be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: I agree 100% that formatting should be done outside the db!!

Comment: @SeanLange HOLY COW!  I had no idea that the performance was that bad.

Comment: Yeah I too was pretty shocked when I first discovered it. It seems that MS has really code under the hood for that one. >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @Date varchar(12)='2012-01-29'
 SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(@Date,4) + SUBSTRING(@Date,6,2) + SUBSTRING(@Date,9,2)), 'MM-dd-yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS Result
```

This is a little bit heavy on processing, but it works.

This answer also assumes that *ALL* values in the date text column are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.  If you have any values that aren't formatted that way as strings, then you will run into problems.

Obviously you will need to replace the @Date variable with the name of your date text column. I wanted to provide an example you can run easily to check the answer.